# Building a Andoid browser

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I am new to android studio.. I am building android web browser for my pleasure. Here, I'm confused about the adding new **tabs**. I used fragment for tabs. I created a button on mainactivity layout and when clicked the button it gonna add new fragment to fragment container..

something like this,

```
public void add_tab()
{
    id++;
    int next_id = id+1;
    String tag = String.valueOf(id);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle ();
    bundle.putString ("tag",tag);
    bundle.putInt ("id",id);
    bundle.putInt ("next_id",next_id);

    final FrameLayout tab_hosting_frame = new FrameLayout(getApplicationContext ());
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams_match_parent_match_parent = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    tab_hosting_frame.setLayoutParams(layoutparams_match_parent_match_parent);
    tab_hosting_frame.setBackgroundColor (Color.BLUE);
    tab_hosting_frame.setId (id);

    FragmentManager fragment_manager1 = getSupportFragmentManager ();
    New_Tab new_tab_fragment = new New_Tab ();
    FragmentTransaction fr_transaction = fragment_manager1.beginTransaction ();
    fr_transaction.add ((tab_hosting_frame.getId ()),new_tab_fragment,tag);
    fr_transaction.addToBackStack ("Fragment Add");
    //new_tab_fragment.setArguments (bundle);
    new_tab_fragment.setArguments (bundle);
    fr_transaction.commit ();

    tab_hosting_layout.addView (tab_hosting_frame);

    //tab_hosting_layout.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);

}
```

I tried this way also

```
public View create_tab()
{
    id++;
    String tag = String.valueOf(id);
    linflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View tab_view = new View (getApplicationContext ());
    tab_view = linflater.inflate(R.layout.new_tab_view, null);
    TextView show_id = (TextView)tab_view.findViewById (R.id.tab_id);
    show_id.setText (tag);
    tab_hosting_layout.addView (tab_view);
    return  tab_view;
}
```

then execute then when button clicked,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);
    tab_hosting_layout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById (R.id.tab_host);
    add_tab_button = (Button) findViewById (R.id.add_tab_button);
    add_tab_button.setOnClickListener (
                            new View.OnClickListener ()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v)
                                {
                                    add_tab ();
                                    //or
                                    //create_tab ();
                                }
                            }
                    );
```

In 2nd methode, thing is, when I click the back button once ,all added tabs(views) are gone once. not step by step one by one..

Is this methode ok?? or is there another methode or way to create unlimited tabs like in normal web browser? I am bit confused weather iam wrong or not..

If u guys know help me with any solution...

Comment: Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)